# Как в easyii подключить News?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем хай. 
Как в easyii подключить модуль News именно в адмике, чтобы можно было добавлять новости? Он там уже есть с коробки, но я не знаю как его подключить =( Даж не знаю в каких файлах искать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зайдите как root и включите в Modules. Посмотрите как это работает на их демо-сайте в http://demo.easyiicms.com/admin/ (root:root)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov У меня нет вкладки Modules http://prntscr.com/fzppk1 Где её можно включить?